# Fins the number of all possible values for the sweets he has given the following conditions?

Tags: number-theory

[image]

**MyApproach**

When divided by $12$,$16$ and $18$ leaves remainder $1$ and when divided by $17$ leaves remainder $0$.

I also cannot find options also helpful while solving the problem

> How can I approach towards the problem?

Comment: Write $N=144k+1$. Then make $8k+1$ divisible by 17.

Comment: @Aravind Can you explain in detail why you took Lcm of $12$,$16$ and $18$ and also why you wrote $8$k+1

Comment: 144 (mod 17)=8. If $N-1$ is divisible by $a,b,c$ then it is divisible by their LCM.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct but the questions is how to generate the candidates.

1. Find the first number that works.

   Start with the largest number, $18$ in this case. You start with $19$ because that has a remainder of $1$ when divided by $18$ but it doesn't work for $12$, $16$ or $17$ so you keep adding $18$ to that number until you get a multiple of $17$. This gives you $289$ which happens to be the first number that works for all three numbers.
2. To preserve the remainder property, you add the least common multiple of $12$, $16$, $17$ and $18$ to $289$ until you get to $10000$. All of those numbers will work. The least common multiple of $12$, $16$, $17$ and $18$ is $2448$ so you get $289$, $2737$, $5185$ and $7633$.